# Loop through controls inside HTML unordered list in code-behind

Tags: c#, html

I have added controls as following in ul through code behind

```
HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
  ul.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li>"));
  ul.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='" + url + "' alt='" + column.ColumnName.Split('_')[1] + " '/>"));
  ul.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input type='hidden' value='" + column.ColumnName.Split('_')[2] + "' />"));
  ul.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</li>"));
```

Now I want to loop through each control inside ul and find out image tag and hidden field.Please help.I have tried as follow but it is giving error:

```
foreach (HtmlGenericControl c in ul.Controls)
{
 HtmlGenericControl img = (HtmlGenericControl)ul.FindControl("img");
}
```

Comment: What error is it giving??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem, which causes an exception is that you are doing a `foreach` over all `Controls` in the `ul`, but you use type `HtmlGenericControl` for the children while they are just simple `LiteralControls`. So the foreach tries to cast `LiteralControl` to `HtmlGenericControl` and throws exception because it is not possible.

Furthermore, a `LiteralControl` is, as the name says, just a literal, so it doesn't know it is a `img` tag. It only knows the full definition `<img src='' alt=''/>` as its text.

To make your requirement possible, you would have to construct the `ul` contents using `HtmlGenericControls`, which you could then query more easily.

```
HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
var img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
img.Attributes.Add("src", "url");
li.Controls.Add(img);
ul.Controls.Add(li);
```

Also, to search within this, you will need to go recursively, because the result is a tree of controls:

```
public HtmlGenericControl FindImg(HtmlGenericControl control)
{            
    foreach (var child in control.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
    {
        if (child.TagName == "img") return child; //found img               

        //not found, recurse into child
        var result = FindImg(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null; //no img found
}
```

Comment: hii .Thank you very much .Could you please tell how can we access alt attribute of image tag in findimg method .

Comment: The method returns a `HtmlGenericControl` so you can use the `Attributes` property

Comment: I tried like this :img.Attributes["alt"].ToString() but not getting correct output.

Comment: Are you actually setting the attribute? In my sample code I only set the `src` and I set it to an empty value.

Comment: Yes I have set it like this: img.Attributes.Add("alt", "1");

Comment: What output are you getting? I have just tested the following code and it works: `img.Attributes.Add("alt", "sadsaf"); Debug.WriteLine(img.Attributes["alt"]);`

Comment: Im so sorry martin .It was silly mistake from my side.Thanks for all your time and help.

Comment: No problem :-) . If that solves your question, please consider accepting the answer so that it is shown as resolved.